# Kali Linux Interface problems not getting mon0

Tags: wireless-networking

I have one problem I was playing with air crack and my monitor mode interface is mon0 but now when i put wlan0 in monitor mode is show wlan0mon 
I want my mon0 back

Answer (score 1):

Kali Linux updates their software and if you choose to update your version you may have to relearn how to use the updated software, In your case they updated aircrack if you don't like this version you will have to uninstall aircrack and download the older version, Another thing you could do is remove Kali Linux from your computer and use version 1.0.9 and if you update it dont update aircrack, You should read their forums the user's have been talking about this for over a month

Comment: I thought I should give you the official site for Kali Linux since their is a fake site with pretty much the same name   - ---https://forums.kali.org/forumdisplay.php?1-Kali-Linux-Forums